# How do I convert a fractional decimal to a whole number in Swift

Tags: swift

What is the easiest way to convert the fractional part of a float decimal (the part on the right) to a whole number integer.

For example:

`0.25` converts to `25`

`0.09` converts to `9`

`0.90` converts to `90`

I've tried several ways, including converting the float to a string and extracting the fraction, but for some reason it leaves off any trailing zeros. For example 0.90 would convert to a string as 0.9.

Comment: Are you limited to two digits after the dot? If not, how can you tell `0.9` from `0.90` and `0.900`?

Comment: Multiply by 100 then convert to Int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
let a = 0.90
let fractionalPart = a.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 1.0)
let modifiedFractionalPart = Int(fractionalPart * 100.0)
let string = String(modifiedFractionalPart)

// prints 90
```

If you aren't allowed to multiply by `100.0`, meaning you don't actually have to limit your fractional part to two decimal places, rather you need to have the whole part after the `.` then use the following:

```
let a = 0.09017
let fractionalPart = String(a).components(separatedBy: ".")[1]  // "09017"
```

Then if you have to convert it to an `Int` just do:

```
let fractionalPartInt = Int(fractionalPart) // 09017
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple's [Foundation Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation) provides a way to do this:

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.multiplier = 100
print(numberFormatter.string(from: 0.25))
```

Specific documentation for NumberFormatter [is also available](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter)

The advantage of using the NumberFormatter is that it is:

- More modular -- if you need to change the conversion factor, just change the multiplier
- More expressive -- having self-documenting code is extremely useful when viewing an old project